# Почему не работает Imask?

Tags: javascript

```js
IMask(
  document.getElementById(".phones"),
  {
    mask: '+{7}(000)000-00-00'
  }
);
```

```html
<body>
<label class="slovo" for="phone"> Номер телефона</label>
            <input type="phone" id="phones" placeholder="Номер телефона" class="phones">
       
            </body>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что не `document.getElementById(".phones"),`, а `document.getElementById("phones"),`